# How to check if a station is locked using powershell

Tags: powershell, wtsapi32

I understand that it is possible to check the state of a computer using wtsapi32.dll using c#. but is it possible to do that using powershell?

Comment: You can use exactly the same C# code, load it via `Add-Type` and use the resulting class from PowerShell, if that suffices.

Comment: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Remote-Logon-Status-d8c2318a

Comment: Or the available PowerShell methods from http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/0e43993a-895a-4afe-a2b2-045a5146048a

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been very helpful